# "Mandatory field "..."is missing a value" when using metadata on Page

Tags: dxa, content-manager, sites-9, dxa2.2

Metadata fields are added to Page schema.
1 metadata field in (Embedded Schema) is **mandatory**.

[image]

On page tab-General you fill in the (mandatory) metadata fields.
On Save it says "Mandatory field "..."is missing a value".

On page tab-Design on a region Main the metadata fields are visible and input. the message comes from there, all fields are empty and never stored. also no relation with the page metadata.

#### UPDATE-1:

Page metadata is visible in tab-General, is aspected and Ok. Mandatory field is visible and is filled.
[image]

In second tab, same page metadata is displayed in Main region. But schema main Region didn't contains it. On Save not always (but often) this message is given for mandatory field. Workaround is to fill it in in tab 2, that fields are never stored which is correct, metadata filled on tab-1 is correct after save. Did not aspect metadata in that region main on tab-2.

[image]

#### Questions

- Bug site 9 (and fix)?
- What is the workaround optional fields/metadata on region schema/...?

Comment: Frankly, I don’t fully understand what you are describing. Can you elaborate/reformulate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your region schema is having metadata which is why you are seeing it when you are adding a component to the region or during page creation. Can you open your region schema and refractor the metadata?

Additionally, there is a hotfix from SDL for items having [special characters in metadata](https://gateway.sdl.com/apex/communityknowledge?articleName=000012744) that might be worth applying in your environment as well. Hope it helps!

Comment: Tried to reconstruct it, does not occur again.

Comment: @FritsLesterhuis, Are you saying that the issue is resolved? If so, could you update the details in a form of an answer and post it? Thank you

Comment: It is happening consequent in acceptance environment. O,T is good. [Main] Region has no metadata but Page schema Metadata is shown in the interface. When add in Region schema 1 Metadata Field then only that is displayed (as aspected). I compared all page/region/entity schema's.

Comment: When Page has 2 Regions both gets the Page Metadata. On Save custom has to fill in only in one region mandatory field. For me it a bug (in interface) and will ask for patch.

Comment: Sounds good. It would be good to have an answer with the SDL hotfix ID, whenever it is available. I have not seen the above behavior

Comment: It's hard to tell, but validation errors that stop happening might be from the Page's data being out of sync with the Schema. Perhaps that's why it differs across environments. Otherwise, it could be related to the content -- a mandatory field in a set of the embedded field will trigger validation only if there are other "sibling" fields filled out. Otherwise, the field itself isn't present in the item's source (XML) and validation doesn't apply (until it or another field actually has a value).